# spring email buttons not working

Tags: java, html, spring, jakarta-mail

I want to send a email message, Will have 1 link to load image from a url.

Then 2 buttons. one button to re direct to `google.com` and one link to redirect `cnn.com`

```
        @Autowired
        public JavaMailSender emailSender;  
        MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        helper.setTo("ratfat@gmail.com");
        helper.setSubject("Test subject");

        String googleLink="http://google.com";
        String cnnLink="http://cnn.com";

        String emailContent="\r\n" + 
                "<html>\n" + 
                "                      <body> \n" + 
                "                         <div align='center'>\n" + 
                "                            <div style='text-align:center;'>\n" + 
                "                               <IMG src='https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png' height='75' width='150'>\n" + 
                "                           </div>\n" + 
                "   \n" + 
                "                            <br/><br/>\n" + 
                "                            Would you like to take it?<br/><br/><br/> \n" + 
                "                            <br/>          \n" + 
                "                           <input type=\"button\" id=\"acceptAcct\" onclick=\"location.href='"+googleLink+"';\"  style=\"width:10em;height:5em\" value=\"Click to load google\" />    \n" + 
                "                           <input type=\"button\" id=\"rejectAcct\" onclick=\"location.href='"+cnnLink+"';\" style=\"width:10em;height:5em\" value=\"Click to load CNN\" />                 \n" + 
                "                         </div>\n" + 
                "                           \n" + 
                "                      </body>\n" + 
                "                   </html>\n";

        helper.setText(emailContent, true);
        message.setContent(message, "text/html");
        emailSender.send(message);
```

I copy the html printed out to a simple test.html and it works well in my browse.

But when the email is recieved, i try clicking the button nothing happens.
In the email ,when i use chrome debug to see the code, the input buttons are like below.

```
<input type="submit" id="m_-5702442034034898245acceptAcct" style="width:10em;height:5em" value="Click to load google">

<input type="submit" id="m_-5702442034034898245rejectAcct" style="width:10em;height:5em" value="Click to load cnn">
```

1). The id is differnt, i dont know where the numbers came from.

2.) The `onclick=\"location.href='"+googleLink+"';\"` are not there as part of input button.

Answer (score 0):

There are significant limits on the type of html you can use in an email message, and every mail client will impose different limits.  Generally, these limits aren't documented, but [this](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) might help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

try this:`"<a href= '"+googleLink+"'  >    \n"+ "                           <input type=\"button\"style=\"width:10em;height:5em\" value=\"Click me to accept\" />    \n" +  "</a>\n"+`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).